# sql: unwrap a selection as a scalar

Tags: sql, postgresql

When a postgres query returns a single row and single column, its value can be accessed as a scalar by "reselecting" it as shown below.

```
with some_val as (
    select 'abc123'
)

select
    (select * from some_val), -- Type: text
```

That works great to hack variables into ANSI SQL but gets messy when the value is used repeatedly.

Is there a more concise way to express that operation through a typecast or generic "unwrap" function?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I do this with a `params` CTE:

```
with params as (
      select 'abc123' as x
     )
select x, x*2
from params cross join
     . . .
```

Note that this allows you to define multiple parameters in the same CTE.

Comment: that totally works in the example i provided so thanks for that! In a more practical example where the values of each successive cte depends on the value of previous ctes it doesn't solve the verbosity issue as much as I was hoping for. Do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: @OliverRice . . . This answers the question that you asked here -- and actually with a construct that I do regularly use in queries.  If you have a *different* question, then ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: the question specifies a typecast or "unwrap" function based solution. That was included for the reason listed in my previous comment. Thanks again, I'll accept your answer if no one can provide a solution meeting that requirement